# Párametro de consulta en access dependiente de una celda en Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, macros

Quiero saber si es posible que un parámetro de una consulta en Access 2013 dependa de la celda A1 en un libro "Libro1" de excel, una sentencia imaginariamente de este estilo:

SELECT *

FROM clientes

WHERE tipo_clientes= --aqui el valor de la celda A1 del libro "libro1"--

---

Se me ocurrió que un camino posible es haciendo una función en VBA access que haga la conexión con el libro, guarde el valor en una variable y lo devuelva como return de la función

---

El problema es que no se como hacer la conexión con excel para la función

¿Alguien sabe algunauna manera de lograr esto? o
¿ si existe otra manera más sencilla de lograrlo?

Comment: Ya lo logré Vinculé la hoja de excel como una tabla e hice referencia a las celdas mediante consultas

Comment: Enrique: Si encuentras la respuesta, no olvides [publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.